# Elastic Search : Highlighted field not always returned

Tags: java, elasticsearch, highlighting

Using Java API, I need to be able to retrieve the field/highlighted field associated with the query. So I'm adding the `_all` field (or else `*`) to the query and highlighted field to the response.
It works most of the time, but not always. Here is a snippet :

```
        final BoolQueryBuilder boolQueryBuilder = QueryBuilders.boolQuery();

        Arrays.asList(query.split(" "))
                .stream()
                .map(QueryParser::escape)
                .map(x -> String.format("*%s*", x))
                .forEach(x -> {
                    boolQueryBuilder.should(
                            QueryBuilders.queryStringQuery(x)
                                    .field("_all")
                                    .allowLeadingWildcard(true));
                });

        SearchResponse response = client
                .prepareSearch()
                .setSize(10)
                .addHighlightedField("*")
                .setHighlighterRequireFieldMatch(false)
                .setQuery(boolQueryBuilder)
                .setHighlighterFragmentSize(40)
                .setHighlighterNumOfFragments(40)
                .execute()
                .actionGet();
```

Any idea on why the `field` field as well as the `highlightedField` is not always accessible in the response given that it is technically always queried?

Comment: Hi , I am not able to understand . Could you please give real time example with dummy data in your scenario ?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure but I think you might be looking for this :-

```
String aQueryWithPartialSerach = null;
final BoolQueryBuilder aBoolQueryBuilder = new BoolQueryBuilder();

 // Enabling partial sarch
        if (query.contains(" ")) {
            List<String> aTokenList = Arrays.asList(query.split(" "));
            aQueryWithPartialSerach = String.join(" ", aTokenList.stream().map(p -> "*" + p + "*").collect(Collectors.toList()));
        } else {
            aQueryWithPartialSerach = "*" + query + "*";
        }

aBoolQueryBuilder.should(QueryBuilders.queryStringQuery(aQueryWithPartialSerach));
```